# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I have a problem with my code, I already import serial but has error

**AttributeError:** '`module`' object has no attribute '`Serial`'. My script named `rc_control_test.py`

```
  import serial
  import pygame
  from pygame.locals import *
  class RCTest(object):
  def __init__(self):
      pygame.init()
      self.ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
      self.send_inst = True
      self.steer()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the module `pyserial` installed and not `serial`?

Comment: Need install pyserial or serial, I already install two module in my Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to uninstall the serial and only have pyserial installed. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running the file using python3.6 solved the problem for me.

```
$ python3.6 file.py
```

Best of luck.